# How to center containers in full-width buttons, while at the same time the texts in them should start from left in the same position?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Longer version of the question in other words: How to center [X] widget in a full-width [Y] widget, while at the same time the [Z] widget with random width in [X] should start from the left in the same position as other [Z] widgets in other [Y] widgets?

After making the translations, I realized I couldn’t use hardcoded values in this case. Dynamic subcontainer width support is needed.

I tried to play with IntrinsicWidth but had no luck. I don't think the problem can be solved with it. Maybe it's a little more complicated, maybe not. Hope somebody can help with a nice solution.

---

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: TestScreen(),
  ));
}

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  final List<String> _randomStringsForSolutions = Iterable<int>.generate(5).map((e) => _randomStringInRandomLength).toList();

  final List<GlobalKey> _globalKeysForSolution2 = Iterable<int>.generate(5).map((e) => GlobalKey()).toList();

  double _biggestWidthForSolution1;
  double _biggestWidthForSolution2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_setBiggestWidthForSolution2);
  }

  _setBiggestWidthForSolution2(_) {
    double biggestWidth;

    for (int i = 0; i < _globalKeysForSolution2.length; i++) {
      GlobalKey globalKey = _globalKeysForSolution2[i];

      RenderBox renderBox = globalKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject();
      if (renderBox == null) {
        continue;
      }

      double width = renderBox.size.width;
      if (biggestWidth != null && biggestWidth >= width) {
        continue;
      }

      biggestWidth = width;
    }

    if (_biggestWidthForSolution2 == biggestWidth) {
      return;
    }

    setState(() {
      _biggestWidthForSolution2 = biggestWidth;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(child: Container(color: Colors.black, width: 2.0)), // a vertical line in the center for easier understanding
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('expected result:  the icons are in line and everything is centered as possible - only works with hardcoded content width', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  ...expectedResult,
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  Text('actual result: the icons are in line, but the content is not really centered', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  ...actualResult,
                  Divider(height: 60.0, thickness: 10.0, color: Colors.green),
                  Text('solution1: the icons are in line and everything is centered as possible - dynamic content width supported', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightGreenAccent)),
                  Text(
                    'solution1 disadvantages: performance problems are possible because of re-renders (use-case dependent); a new SizeMeasurer widget class has to be implemented',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  ...solution1,
                  Divider(height: 60.0, thickness: 10.0, color: Colors.green),
                  Text(
                    'solution2: the icons are in line and everything is centered as possible - dynamic content width supported with only one re-render',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightGreenAccent),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'solution2 disadvantages: we need to keep records of global keys',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  ...solution2,
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Expected result with hardcoded content and width settings
  List<Widget> get expectedResult {
    return [
      SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            child: Center(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                    child: Icon(Icons.mood),
                  ),
                  Text('Continue with Facebook'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            child: Center(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                    child: Icon(Icons.mood),
                  ),
                  Text('Continue with Twitter'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }

  /// Actual result when the lengths of the strings are unknown
  List<Widget> get actualResult {
    return List.generate(2, (_) {
      return SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Container(
            width: 200, // THIS CAN NO LONGER BE USED!
            child: Center(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                    child: Icon(Icons.mood_bad),
                  ),
                  Text(_randomStringInRandomLength),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  List<Widget> get solution1 {
    return List.generate(_randomStringsForSolutions.length, (index) {
      return SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Container(
            width: _biggestWidthForSolution1 ?? null,
            child: SizeMeasurer(
              onChange: (sizeOfChild) {
                if (_biggestWidthForSolution1 != null && _biggestWidthForSolution1 >= sizeOfChild.width) {
                  return;
                }
                setState(() {
                  _biggestWidthForSolution1 = sizeOfChild.width;
                });
              },
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                    child: Icon(Icons.mood),
                  ),
                  Text(_randomStringsForSolutions[index]),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  List<Widget> get solution2 {
    return List.generate(_randomStringsForSolutions.length, (index) {
      return SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Container(
            width: _biggestWidthForSolution2 ?? null,
            child: Row(
              key: _globalKeysForSolution2[index],
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  child: Icon(Icons.mood),
                ),
                Text(_randomStringsForSolutions[index]),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}

String get _randomStringInRandomLength {
  Random random = Random();
  int randomInt = random.nextInt(20) + 1;
  return String.fromCharCodes(List.generate(randomInt, (index) => random.nextInt(33) + 89));
}

typedef void OnWidgetSizeChange(Size size);

class SizeMeasurer extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final OnWidgetSizeChange onChange;

  const SizeMeasurer({
    Key key,
    @required this.onChange,
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SizeMeasurerState createState() => _SizeMeasurerState();
}

class _SizeMeasurerState extends State<SizeMeasurer> {
  GlobalKey widgetKey = GlobalKey();
  Size oldSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(postFrameCallback);
    return Container(
      key: widgetKey,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }

  void postFrameCallback(_) {
    BuildContext context = widgetKey.currentContext;
    if (context == null) {
      return;
    }

    Size newSize = context.size;
    if (oldSize == newSize) {
      return;
    }

    oldSize = newSize;
    widget.onChange(newSize);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE - I created two possible solutions and included them in the code above!**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but you will have to set the values after widget is build. Here is the example code I wrote for you in [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/fea023e2c9191faa21d01af92d808ca7) ( https://dartpad.dev/fea023e2c9191faa21d01af92d808ca7 ). The code below runs only once after the widget is build, you may want to modify it to run every time state changes, but it can be easily done :

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHome({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomeState createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  GlobalKey _keyRed = GlobalKey();
  double padding = 0;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _findPosition());
  }

  void _findPosition() {
    final RenderBox renderBoxRed = _keyRed.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final positionRed = renderBoxRed.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    print(positionRed);
    setState(() {
      padding = positionRed.dx;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> titles = ["one", "two", "three", "f"];
    final String longest = titles.reduce((a, b) {
      return a.length > b.length ? a : b;
    });
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          for (var title in titles)
            MyRow(
                title: title,
                alignment: longest == title
                    ? MainAxisAlignment.center
                    : MainAxisAlignment.start,
                padding: longest == title ? 0 : padding,
                rowKey: longest == title ? _keyRed : null),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyRow extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyRow({this.title, this.alignment, this.padding, this.rowKey});
  final String title;
  final MainAxisAlignment alignment;
  final double padding;
  final GlobalKey rowKey;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: alignment,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: padding),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.favorite,
              color: Colors.pink,
              size: 24.0,
              key: rowKey,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Text(title)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Row's fields to get what you're looking for, specifically the size, which can be set to min.

This is the expected result of the code below.
[image]

```
return SizedBox(
      width: double.maxFinite,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.mood),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            Text('Continue with Twitter'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Wrong answer. With your 'solution' the rows are centered, but the icons are not in line with icons in other buttons.

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question, glad you got it sorted out. Happy coding!